# launching parallel processes with exec(). is it possible?

Tags: php, process, exec

I want to run more than 1 php processes using exec(command). Each of these (actually they are the same) may last long, and I dont want wait one to finish than launch another.

in other words, I want

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   exec($command);
}
```

this code to be executed without waiting for return from previous process.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Comment: see also the user entries on the doc page.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. I missed the ">" symbol to properly redirect the output. (blush)

Comment: Actually, (and depending on the OS) you need to redirect ALL three STDIO streams and set the session group.